# Hidden Form Fields: does structure matter?

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

In an HTML form, do the order of the hidden inputs, or the internal structure of the form + inputs make a difference in how the data is interpreted?

For example:

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="x" value="1"><p>...</p>
  <input type="hidden" id="y" value="2"><p>...</p>
...
```

vs:

```
<form>
  <div class="one">
    <input type="hidden" id="x" value="1"><p>...</p>
  </div>

  <div class="one">
    <input type="hidden" id="y" value="2"><p>...</p>
  </div>
```

...

My gut tells me that no, the order and structure of the hidden inputs make no difference, and that the data contained in the POST will be the same, but I'm new to web stuff, so I am not 100% sure.  Is there a difference?

Comment: There would be no difference in the above, however, if you didn't have your p tags then the second version would add extra blank lines where your divs were

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it makes no difference. Using the  method is only useful if you are going to do something dynamic with the hidden fields such as show them based on some criteria the user inputs. To do that you set the disabled attribute to true or false on your event.